# How can I read a line from a Stream to a ReadOnlySpan<char>?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am experimenting with reading data from a `Stream` (in my case is a `StreamReader`) to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`.

When the lines have fixed length there is no problem but when they have **variable** length I don't know how it can be done.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to read a line to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` in some way.

Comment: Why are you using a `Span<T>`?

Comment: Es porque después troceo la línea y realizo llamadas a `decimal.Parse`, `int.Parse`, etc.

Comment: No hablo. Diga me en Engles por favor.

Comment: What's wrong with using [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline)?

Comment: `StreamReader.ReadLine` creates multiple allocations. Internally creates a StringBuilder and after it calls ToString creatin another allocation, so its not optimal. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a4ada5f765646068,references

Comment: There is a reason for that, which is that it is reading from a stream, where the bytes may arrive one after another with a delay. That is why it's called a stream. It flows. If the entire content was in memory so that you could treat it as a span, you would not need to use a stream in the first place.

Comment: I know what a Stream is;). Look at this https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27522 and this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/. The problem with these solutions is that they are read from a Pipe and the pipes only accept a stream of bytes. Internally, Pipe saves a buffer of buffers to fill only what is needed each time a line is encountered and reuse them for the next. I was wondering if there is a way to use a similar system with StreamReader and not with a Byte Pipe. I will use the Pipe I don't see any other way. Thanks guys anyway.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to write to *ReadOnly*Span<char>. Perhaps to Span<char>. And there is no ReadLine overload that does that, unfortunately.

Comment: I dont want to write. I want to read. Anyway i solved the problem.

Comment: @NetDefender, how did you solve it? :)

Comment: @NetDefender Would really like to know how this was solved.